# is win32service library compatible to python3 64bit ? i can't make it even install service on windows

Tags: python, windows, service, 64-bit, pywin32

i am setting up a new windows service using python `win32service library`. I have `python3 x64` on my system (other projects require it to be so). Is `win32service` compatible to `python x64` i am not able to find anything in the documentation

Comment: `pywin32` is available in both 32-bit and 64-bit for Python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6 and 3,7 from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases. The specific module you are asking about it is the extension `pywin32service.pyd` and does not have version information separately documented because it forms part of the `pywin32` package. You can't install it separately because that would make no sense and you also can't import it directly. Install `pywin32` and have your program do `import win32serviceutil, win32service`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and coding it is clear that `pywin32` is available in both `32-bit` and `64-bit` for `Python 2.7`, `3.5`, `3.6` and `3,7`